# Chave estrangeira com UNIQUE

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira

O que acontece se eu colocar uma `foreign key` como `UNIQUE` em uma tabela?

Eu testei essa possibilidade mas talvez eu tenha entendido errado, se aplicarmos uma `UNIQUE` em uma `foreign key` e inserimos o valor errado nessa tabela, esse mesmo valor que foi inserido não será consultado no `inner join`, pois o `id` da **tabela 1** não bate com o `id`da **tabela 2 (que seria a chave estrangeira)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem o campo `User_idUser` (`UNIQUE`) ele é uma chave estrangeira da Tabela `User`,
a próxima imagem é da tabela usuário com um inner join

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1. Não sei se isso se aplica a normalização, mas isso não é uma forma de não repetirmos os dados na tabela?
2. E sobre o dado que está lá presente mas no banco mas não foi consultado com o `inner join` o que fazemos com ele?

Comment: rapaz que pergunta maluca, qual tipo de relacionamento deve essas duas tabelas?

Comment: Acho que vou remover, pois vai ficar fora do escopo, mas a pergunta central é: Teria algum problema eu inserir uma restrição de UNIQUE na minha chave estrangeira?

Comment: Colocar UNIQUE como restrição não tem nenhuma influência na junção, o que acontece é que você deixa o relacionamento como sendo (0,1):1. No seu caso o significado é que cada user só pode estar relacionado a no máximo 1 celular.

Comment: Depende do proposito ... porque `unique` garante que na relação só tenha um código e não pode duplicar ... !!!

Comment: Este modelo está estranho pois se a relação é 1:1 em tese deveria estar tudo na mesma tabela , mas só entendendo o problema para opinar , mas um campo pode ser fk e unique.

Comment: @RodrigoPires minha resposta te ajudou? Caso positivo, peço que por favor que marque a resposta como "aceita", para que sua pergunta saia dos filtros de perguntas não respondidas do Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode, sim, adicionar a restrição `UNIQUE` a qualquer coluna que desejar, incluindo colunas de `foreign keys`.

Essa é uma das estratégias possíveis para forçar relacionamentos do tipo 1 para 1 em tabelas separadas.

Fazer isso não é tão comum, pois dados relacionados 1 para 1 são normalmente armazenados em uma mesma tabela do banco de dados.

Mas existe, sim, alguns casos de usos reais, sendo o principal deles, o caso em que a segunda tabela é muito raramente populada. Esse cenário está relacionado com o tópico Armazenamento de Matrizes Esparsas (http://www.inf.ufes.br/~luciac/mn1/armazenamento-matrizes-esparsas.pdf), e está exemplificado abaixo:

```
Tabela 1
+------------------------------+
| id email                     |
+------------------------------+
| 1 email1@email.xyz           |
| 2 email2@email.xyz           |
| 3 email3@email.xyz           |
| 4 email4@email.xyz           |
| 5 email5@email.xyz           |
| ...                          |
| 99999999 email9999@email.xyz |
+------------------------------+

Tabela 2
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id tabela1_id coluna1 coluna2 coluna3 coluna4 coluna5 ... coluna1000 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 5 1 0 1 0 1 ... 1                                                  |
| 2 9999 1 1 1 1 1 ... 0                                               |
| 3 999999 1 1 1 1 1 ... 0                                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

No cenário acima, você tem 99.999.999 registros na Tabela 1, mas apenas 3 registros na Tabela 2 (nesse exemplo, a coluna tabela1_id é foreign key com restrição `UNIQUE`). E como a Tabela 2 é muito extensa (1000 colunas), você poupou espaço de armazenamento.

Vamos estimar a economia de espaço de armazenamento acima: você deixou de armazenar `1000` colunas para `99.999.999 - 3` registros, ou seja, `99.999.996.000` valores a menos não foram armazenados no banco. Supondo que cada valor não armazenado economize 1 bit de espaço, teríamos uma **economia de mais de 11 gigabytes** `(1000*(99999999-3)/8/1024/1024/1024)`.

Claro que esse exemplo é apenas ilustrativo, pois os bancos de dados podem possuir algumas otimizações para economizar espaço de armazenamento com matrizes esparsas.