# Qual a função da constraint Unique em chaves estrangeiras?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Se a chave estrangeira sempre vai referenciar uma chave primária, que por definição é única, então qual a necessidade de definir a constraint 'unique' em chaves estrangeiras?

Comment: Se a chave estrangeira for única, significa que cada registro da outra tabela só pode ser referenciado uma vez. Isso pode ser desejável ou não, depende do seu modelo de dados. Por exemplo, se uma tabela de endereços tem chave estrangeira única para uma tabela de cidades, só poderá existir um único endereço em cada cidade (ou seja, nesse exemplo claramente a chave estrangeira não deve ser única).

Comment: Por algum motivo do modelo se quer que na tabela referenciada só exista uma referência , por exemplo tabela "clientes" , "conta correntes" e "cobrança" para um débito em conta a tabela  "cobrança" tem como fk  "clientes" e "conta correntes" mas só se permite uma conta na cobrança , seria a unique na "cobrança" , exemplo ruim talvez mas não me ocorreu outro.

Comment: -> [Chave estrangeira com UNIQUE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/402678/70)